# How to add MySQL code inside code?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from dosyabegeni where veri_id=''.get_custom_field('dwcode').''");
```

I would like to place the following PHP code:

```
 <?php get_custom_field('dwcode'); ?>
```

.. What's wrong?

```
  =''.get_custom_field('dwcode').''");
```

Main Code:

```
 <?php
 include('/home/test/public_html/EntegreOz/DosyaBegeni/config.php');
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from dosyabegeni where veri_id=".get_custom_field('dwcode')."");


 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {

 $sira_id=$row['sira_id'];
 $veri_id=$row['veri_id'];
  $begeni=$row['begeni'];

 ?>
```

Thank you!

*I know.. I could not tell more, Im sorry for the English*

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Please **STOP** using `mysql_query` like you have here. You're going to get yourself into serious trouble. This code has a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php) that can be [automatically exploited](http://sqlmap.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You have too many single quotes (`'`):

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from dosyabegeni where veri_id='".get_custom_field('dwcode')."'");
```

However, Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: If you know about PDO and `mysqli` then you'd know better than to jam in an unescaped value. That you got the code working only makes this gigantic exploit now functional.

Comment: @tadman: Hence the warning. I've stopped dealing with escaping long ago with the introduction of prepared statements. I've warned the OP about the functions deprecation twice. If that's not enough, than SQL injection it is.

Comment: +1, and [here's](https://github.com/rockerest/nox/blob/master/classes/backbone/Database.php) a SUPER BASIC class to make PDO queries a little less difficult.  Construct with `$db = new Database( $username, $password, $database, $host, 'mysql');` and query with `$db->qwv( $sql, array( $val1, $val2, ... ) );`.  It will require a little PDO knowledge, but I can't agree more that PDO is the best way to go.

Comment: You can address the syntax problem without re-posting a working, and extremely hazardous statement. If you want to encourage people to update, don't make it easier to stick with what they've got and muddle along doing it 1990s style.

Comment: @tadman You have no idea what `get_custom_field()` does.  Maybe it escapes and cleans input. This could be perfectly safe.  Madara's caveat of "don't use mysql_* functions" and "you should learn about prepared statements" is plenty to negate the "dangerous" cause for a downvote.  Plus, the [reasons for a downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) aren't what's dangerous, they're what's dangerously *incorrect*.  Unfortunately, mysql_* is still correct.

Comment: If it's not **obvious** the value is escaped, it cannot be **presumed** to be escaped. The PHP community around here is so hazardously casual about escaping and it's no wonder PHP sites are notoriously easy to hack. This is absolutely not the case with other languages like Ruby or Python. `mysql_query` is not correct unless used *with* escaping. I'll downvote all answers that are, by any definition, completely unsafe to use.

Comment: @tadman you're the incorrigible kind of person who answers a question like "How to add MySQL code inside code?" with "PHP SUCKS REWRITE IT IN PYTHON."  Good luck in the real world.

Comment: You're missing the point. The MySQL tag on Stack Overflow is absolutely *cluttered* with PHP questions showing a reckless disregard for escaping. Other communities use drivers equivalent to PDO and consider doing something like `mysql_query` to be Doing It Wrong. That you think it's "okay" to continue using this clap-trap interface that's always one missing line away from your site being taken over speaks a lot about your attitude. I just want the answers here to promote best practices, not simply fix superficial problems.

Comment: @tadman You're so utterly wrong in every judgement you've made about me that I can't help but respond to this. Your lack of simple reading comprehension is also astounding. Let me just leave a quote from *this comment thread* here to prove you wrong: "I can't agree more that PDO is the best way to go". Additionally, "Unfortunately, mysql_* is still correct" doesn't mean it's "okay" it means that it will *work*. SO is about _answering_ questions that a person asks. Finally, your statement about presumption is absurd, since SO is largely about guessing what will work given limited information.

Comment: So basically you're saying adding `mysql_real_escape_string` to the answer you provided isn't appropriate? It would make it a safe solution. I'm not asking for people to convert to X language, just practice safe SQL.

Comment: Would you mind stopping to spam my inbox please? Take it to a chat room.

Answer (score -2):

Incorrect quoting:

```
$sql=  ... snip ... where veri_id=" .get_custom_field('dwcode'). ");
                                   ^-- remove ''                 ^--remove ''
```

`'` will not "exit" a `"`-quoted string.